# Smoke looks blurry

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine, smoke-simulation

So I am working on a project for school, using smoke with different colours to present a different kind of gases. I was new to Blender, and I spent some time learning to. I was doing a simple tryout to see if I can get what I want.

However, the smoke turns out so blurry and grainy. My computer is not able to do high-resolution division and I am having four outflows in one domain, will that be a problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: unfortunately yes, it has to do with the resolution division. The higher it is the less grainy it will be.

Comment: I once try 200, but it takes forever to render, but it still looks pretty much the same...